# Is 朱日和 the homophone word of 诛日俄？

Tags: word-choice

Yesterday China held a large scale field parade in the training base of 朱日和. Usually a place is named after something or someone, but that name sounds like a name of a former celebrity, but there was not such a person in China's history, so it is not surprising for me to think it might be a homophone of something. Do you think 诛日俄 is a justified choice?

Comment: https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/309171117833673164.html：朱日和”系蒙古语的译音，意为“心脏”

Comment: 像歐美一樣，軍事基地只會建立在荒蕪人煙的地方。這地方以前就是那樣的。

Answer (score 3):

The base is located in the 朱日和, which is a town in Inner Mongolia, it means 'courage' in mongolian language.

This town includes 15 villages, the training base is built from a 1950s armored troops training base.

So I don't think they give a new "fancy" name to that town.

Answer (score 0):

我天朝华夏爱好和平，只会谴责，何来诛日俄这么大火气！何况俄罗斯是我战略合作伙伴，钓鱼岛争端也没敢说诛日啊。希望你汉语好能看懂。长者教育我们，你们这些个外国人啊，还是要加强学习，提高姿势水平…不说了，我已经感觉到了时间在飞快地流逝了-1s-1s-1s.....

Comment: @J Wang Don't tell me your ancestors are docile and not ambitious. During Mao's rule, the slogan "Surpass the US and the UK" was very popular. Don't you find any similarity of President Xi and Chairman Mao?

Comment: @NanningYouth your chinese level impressed my very much!!!my grandpa's father is an soldier during world war 2,fighting the fxxking japenese.the slogan you mentioned is just the annual steel product surpass us and uk,not everything,not gdp,not citizen's average standard of living.in that times,chinese local goverments forced people  melt their pots pans axe spoon to meet mao's goal to please him.and you said they are similar,for this aspect,yes it is.pleasw tell me you are not a chinese or chinese officer...I dont want to get in trouble

Comment: It is the total strength of the country, not only the steel output. Chairman Mao was not so low in his strategies, though he might be naive to some point. What kind of trouble will you be in? All things are known through the Internet or other knowledgeable people.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like 中日俄， representing three countries, China, Japan and Russia.

It's a place's name, so skip my answer here.